# socket.io: how to get socket object in room, in a multi-processes environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I use socketio Redis adapter and having multiple socketio processes running. I want to get a list of all socket objects in a room, is that possible?

I tried the following line, but it doesn't work cross-processes.

```
var socket = io.sockets.connected[id]
```

Comment: Unless you coordinate so that all sockets in a particular room are on one server, you will have to query each server to get a list of users in a given room or you could store all join/leave info in redis so you could query it all from there.

Comment: I also think that storing each connect/disconnect on Redis is the way to go. Unfortunately it's not designed to have such a feature..